# Visual Basic Beginner ..SubStrings

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to figure out this simple question! The language is Visual Basic! The Question is below:

"Users of a computer program often like to enter numbers with commas inserted in the middle, such as "1,234,000,688". Most computer languages consider this format to be non numeric. Write a program that inputs a number containing no more than three commas, and produces a string containing the same number without the commas"

When I enter this number: 1,234,000,688 and hit Display in Visual Basic I get this error message --> Argument is out of range Exception was unhanded

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening because I'm within my strUserInput length.

My Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        'Variable declarations
        Dim strUserInput = txtUserInput.Text
        Dim strOutputNumber1 As String
        Dim strOutputNumber2 As String
        Dim strOutputNumber3 As String
        Dim strOutputNumber4 As String
        ' 1,234,000,688

        strOutputNumber1 = strUserInput.Substring(0, 1)
        strOutputNumber2 = strUserInput.Substring(2, 4)
        strOutputNumber3 = strUserInput.Substring(5, 8)
        strOutputNumber4 = strUserInput.Substring(9, 12)
        lblDisplayNumber.Text = strOutputNumber1 & strOutputNumber2 &         strOutputNumber3 & strOutputNumber4

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        lblDisplayNumber.Text = String.Empty
        txtUserInput.Text = String.Empty

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The second argument to `Substring` is the length of the substring, not the end point.  [See the documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Your solution also relies on the assumption that the commas are at specific pre-defined places in the input string. This is not specified as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that exception because of the way you're using substring, the last one there starts at index 9 and extends 12 characters...that would be a 22 character number, and the text you have as input is probably much shorter. You don't need to make things overly complicated for yourself using substrings, all of the above code could be greatly condensed and cleaned up by simply using [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        lblDisplayNumber.Text = txtUserInput.Text.Replace(",", "")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        lblDisplayNumber.Text = String.Empty
        txtUserInput.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub
End Class
```